# How to sum all the fractions in a loop?

Tags: python

I'd like to calculate the sum of the following numbers using a loop

```
1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7 + . . . + 95/97 + 97/99
```

Print the sum

So far this is what I wrote but I could only get it to print the fractions

```
s = ''
for j in range(30, 0, -1):
    s += "{}/{} + ".format(31-j, j)
    sum = +=j
print sum
```

Comment: Ignoring the loop for the moment, do you know how to add two fractions together?

Comment: Your code does not really seem to be related to the task.

Comment: Your code concatenates string representations; it doesn't do any arithmetic.  Start over and work with the math first.

Comment: Are you looking for the actual `Fraction` or a `float` number?

Comment: You should consider revising your question (the relevant links already posted below). You should add some valid sample input and your example code should bear some  basic resemblance to what you are trying to do. At present it seems like you are trying to sum a load of integers. Another winning approach would be to [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=python+fractions) python fractions. See the top two results.

Answer (score -1):

To sum up the fractions of x/(x+2) where x is odd, you can use `range(start, stop, step)` where the start is `1`, stop is `98`, and the step size is `2`.  Passing this to `sum` will give you the answer:

```
sum(x/(x+2.0) for x in range(1,98,2))
```

Comment: `range(1, 98, 2)`, ends at `97/99`

Comment: lol, `x/(x+2)` for integers will always be `0` (in Py2, as AChampion mentions)

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, opinion-based, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.

Comment: @TemporalWolf not in Py3

Comment: @AChampion `print sum` in OPs code necessitates Py2... but I did add a note, as you are correct in the general sense.